# What is that 4th medallion pictured?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

At the bottom left

This is the items page for The Legend Of Zelda: A Link To The Past.  Some of these are inventory items, while others are either items found in the overworld or in Dungeons.  I don't recognize the 4th medallion (marked with a red square).

[image]

Comment: There were only 3 magic medallions in the game, so some context on where this image is from might be in order. The manual? Or somewhere else? Frankly, even the "clothes" aren't making much sense to me - I didn't know there was sleeves and non-sleeves.  Oh!  A shrubbery too.

Comment: @Radhil It's from the *Legend of Zelda Art and Artifacts* book, although I don't own a copy so can't check if it's perhaps just concept art and they discarded it keeping the other three medallion designs.

Comment: @Nemon27 - that would be my guess too - closest guess I can hit is it's an early version of a light medallion

Comment: @Radhil The Quake Medallion (immediate left of the boxed mystery medallion) has a different design to how it appears in game so I feel like this is almost definitely concept art, but I don't have more than a strong hunch to give a concrete answer.

Comment: That's the Mystical Medal. It confers the ability to plug in a USB first time, without having to turn it over and then back again.

Comment: @Valorum - */dopeslap*

Comment: I can confirm that it's from the Art and Artifacts book but there is no indication that it is "concept" only art - it is listed in the same layout as the rest of the games' game elements

Answer (score 8):

I'm unable to find any concrete evidence revealing the identity of this medallion, but I'm *very* confident it's concept art. Let's take a look at some other pictures to see why.

Here's a close up of the four medallions from your original photo, which I've taken from the same book; *[The Legend of Zelda: Art and Artifacts](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Legend-Zelda-Art-Artifacts/dp/1506703356)*.

[image: Four Medallions Together]

In the section for the pixel art of *A Link to the Past*, we're treated to this image.

[image: Pixel Art Medallions]

As you can see, there's definitely only three medallions used in the game, although I suppose that's why you're asking in the first place. Here's where it gets interesting; from the *Zelda Wiki* page for the Quake Medallion we find this image.

[image: Quake Medallion from Wiki]

The wiki states that this is the artwork from the game's instruction manual, and it's certainly a closer representation of the pixelated design. The fact that the *Art and Artifacts* book doesn't include this design, and that the only designs which match the manual and pixel designs are the top two, leads me to believe that this book isn't a complete compendium of Nintendo's Zelda artwork and only features some of their works (probably allowing them to sell another edition in a few years time).

As such, I strongly believe the bottom two medallions are concept art for the Quake Medallion, or perhaps the Quake Medallion and a fourth medallion which was later scrapped. As Radhil suggests in the comments, it's not too dissimilar from the Light Medallion from *Ocarina of Time*, and not letting good art go to waste could've been recycled and altered after being dropped from *ALTTP*, although this is pure speculation.

Comment: Funnily enough, the design of the fourth medallion reminds me of how the energy balls summoned by the Eher medallion are rotating clockwise around Link before flying away, and there's also exactly 8 balls. Maybe a first design of the Ether medallion?

Answer (score -1):

each medallian is based on natural disasters. you have bombos which acts as wildfires or even volcanoes, ether which acts as either floods or storms, and quake acts as earthquakes. the only one really missing out of those would be a tornado, but that could relate to Ether? not exactly Ether means warm clear skies and the texts from the large tome mentions polar winds meaning a cold front and a warm front meeting. which could cause either a tornado or a hurricane depending on where it sits, so my theory is simply it was scrapped because of the Ether medallion and the close relationship as to which natural disaster it takes. my theory though is that all the medallians originally opened a dark world dungeon bombos would have been used in skull woods. Then the fire rod would be found in the ice palace instead of the blue mail and every dark world dungeon without the explicit word of palace (insinuating made be man or some form of intelligent entity) would use a medallian for entry, misery mire, skull woods, gargoyle domain, and the misery mire. Other idea is four corners use the four medallians trading the gargoyle Domain with the Ice Palace.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this speculation?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.